# Select2 - input field without dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm working with [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and I have a input field where I want to providde search terms.
[image]

As you can see I have a dropdown where I can select or type my own text.

My jquery code:

```
function createQuestionTags(data){
  $(".question").select2({
    createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function () {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            return {
                id: term,
                text: term
            };
        }
    },
    data: data,
    placeholder: "Enter Question",
    allowClear:true
  });
}
```

How can I set that it is just an input field where you can type and not with a dropdownlist?

Comment: mak use of autocomplete extender....

Comment: `.select2-results{
    display:none;
}` in CSS ???

Comment: When I add the css he logically shows no results ...

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dropdown will always be visible because that's how Select2 works. It's a really good library but this happens to be one of the constraints you will have to work through. The very simple reason behind is:

> Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results. — [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

You can try and forcefully hide it using CSS but I haven't tried that.

I recently came across [selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) which is equally good as Select2 and fulfils your requirements.

Comment: And something like this : http://i42.tinypic.com/fyik55.png    Copied it from select2 site